# opengl glLineWidth() doesn't change size of lines

Tags: opengl

I wrote this function, where I set up line width to draw a rectangle, but when calling it, the line width doesn't change at all. How can i use `glLineWidth` correctly?

```
void drawRect(Rectangle &rect)
{
      double x1 = rect.min.x;
      double y1 = rect.min.y;
      double x2 = rect.max.x;
      double y2 = rect.max.y;

      glLineWidth(3.0f);
      glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
            glVertex2d(x1, y1);
            glVertex2d(x2, y1);
            glVertex2d(x2, y2);
            glVertex2d(x1, y2);
      glEnd();

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OpenGL implementations are not required to support rendering of wide lines.

You can query the range of supported line widths with:

```
GLfloat lineWidthRange[2] = {0.0f, 0.0f};
glGetFloatv(GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, lineWidthRange);
// Maximum supported line width is in lineWidthRange[1].
```

The required minimum for both limits is 1.0, meaning that support for line widths larger than 1.0 is not required. Also, drawing wide lines is a deprecated feature, and will not be supported anymore if you move to a newer (core profile) version of OpenGL.

An alternative to drawing wide lines is to render thin polygons instead.

Comment: thank you but what do you mean by "support for line widths larger than 1.0 is not required" ?

Comment: I tried the range query you provided, but the results are both lineWidthRange[0] and lineWidthRange[1] are 1. So I couldn't change the line width?

Comment: Yes, that means that the OpenGL implementation on your machine does not support lines wider than 1.

Comment: oh no, is that because the version is too old?

Comment: Not necessarily. It's completely up to the GPU vendor if they want/can support wide lines. Since it's a deprecated feature, and was always optional, it's well possible that it wouldn't be supported on pretty much any GPU. But I really don't know which vendors/GPUs support wide lines, and which don't.

Comment: Not recognizing 'GLfloat' for me, but I imagine there's something I have to import or prefix it's not suggesting, 'GLES20.' and 'GLES10.' prefixes didn't work.

Comment: @Androidcoder in recent versions of opengl, a float can be used in its place.